# How to serve static files in ejs for dynamic url?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have routes something like this

```
router.get('/home',controller.home)
router.get('/',controller.home)
router.get('/view/:Id/', controller.view);
```

Images are placed in public/img.
I have used this code in index.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The problem is that from home.ejs, I can access the images by using

```
<img src="img/img1.png">
```

But from view.ejs, I cannot access the images using`<img src="img/img1.png">`
When i open view.ejs in my browser, the img source is changed to `<img src=localhost:3000/view/1/img/img1.png>` and is not displayed.

Comment: Use `<img src="/img/img1.png">`

Comment: Wow..thanks..Why does this work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls